# How can I use FSharp.Data with VS 2015?

Tags: f#, visual-studio-2015, f#-data

I'm trying to using FSharp.Data in a script file on a FSharp project, and the error that I'm receiving is:

> Warning       '..\packages\FSharp.Data.2.2.5\lib\net40\FSharp.Data.dll' is
>   not a valid assembly name.

FSharp.Data from https://www.nuget.org/packages/FSharp.Data/

It's the same problem if I try with a F# project for .NET 4.0, .NET 4.5 or .NET 4.6.

**EDIT:** It works fine with '..\packages\FSharp.Data.2.2.5\lib\portable-net40+sl5+wp8+win8\FSharp.Data.dll' but in this portable version only web locations are supported.

Comment: I had no troubles using the `net40` version in VS 2015. Can you post your exact code? (Is everything escaped correctly? Is the relative path correct?)

Comment: There is no code, just the line to use the assembly. 
#r "..\packages\FSharp.Data.2.2.5\lib\net40\FSharp.Data.dll"
I got the same error using a VS 2012 instance. I'm thinking that maybe it is a problem with my .NET or VS instances.

Comment: That's still code :)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I think the problem is string escaping. In the following:

```
#r "..\packages\FSharp.Data.2.2.5\lib\net40\FSharp.Data.dll"
```

The `\n` is interpreted as a new-line character and so it is invalid. But in the following:

```
#r "..\packages\FSharp.Data.2.2.5\lib\portable-net40+sl5+wp8+win8\FSharp.Data.dll"
```

.. there are no special escape sequences in the string. Both of the following should work:

```
#r @"..\packages\FSharp.Data.2.2.5\lib\net40\FSharp.Data.dll"
#r "..\\packages\\FSharp.Data.2.2.5\\lib\\net40\\FSharp.Data.dll"
```

Comment: I can't believe that just happened. The right error to show when it is not possible to find the assembly is: Error  Assembly reference 'SomethingThatDoesntExist.dll' was not found or is invalid. That's why I thought that could be another problem.

Comment: Yes, the error message simply sucks. Open an issue & send a pull request! https://github.com/Microsoft/visualfsharp/

Comment: FSI also supports `/`